# endBackgroundTask: Causing "Terminated due to signal 9"

Tags: ios, xcode, ios9

My app syncs RSS feeds which takes about 15-30 seconds and for each sync I request `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:`. In iOS 7 and iOS 8 everything worked perfectly.

Starting with iOS 9 calling `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask: backgroundTask];` causes the app to crash with Message from debugger:

> Terminated due to signal 9.

From my research, signal 9 means the app using too much memory. When I use instruments, the app never goes over 30mb or 40% cpu.

I know that it's from calling `endBackgroundTask:` because if I don't call it, the app doesn't crash. Yet, once I call endBackgroundTask: the app will crash every time.

I'm not sure what's going wrong here. I've tried everything. Re-writting code, moving code around, commenting out everything except endBackgroundTask:. Any help or insight would be appreciated.

Here's the code:

```
    @interface SyncClass ()

            @property (nonatomic) UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier backgroundTask;
    @end

    -(void)startSync  
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

            [self beginBackgroundUpdateTask];
            // I then call my syncing code [syncClass sync];

        });


            //When sync is done call endBackgroundTask
            [self endBackgroundUpdateTask];
    }    

    - (void) beginBackgroundUpdateTask
    {
        NSLog(@"Background Time:%f",[[UIApplication sharedApplication] backgroundTimeRemaining]);

        self.backgroundTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
            [self endBackgroundUpdateTask];
        }];

    }

    - (void) endBackgroundUpdateTask
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask: self.backgroundTask];
        self.backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
        NSLog(@"Ending background task");
    }
```

Comment: Are you on a background thread?

Comment: Hi, yes the sync method is called from another controller using:            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        
        [syncManger startSync];
        
    });   Just updated question to reflect. Thanks!

Comment: Well, I don't have a good explanation of the termination based on what you've said. Could it be something in the `sync` code, the code you're not showing? Could _that_ be what's using too much memory? This might make sense, because when you call `endBackgroundTask` that's when the runtime suspends you and discovers you're using too much memory in the background (before that, you couldn't be terminated because you were still running). In general, I suggest you take this message seriously: you should already be trying to release resources to reduce memory usage as you go into the background.

Comment: That was my thought too. However, after running the allocations tool, my persistent bytes is 11.25 MBs but Total Bytes is 352.92MB and it still crashes. From my understanding is persistent bytes I need to worry about. Everytime I run the allocations tool, the app crashes while under 20 MB of persisted bytes. Thanks,

Comment: Well, experiment a different way. What happens if you _do_ call `endBackgroundTask:` but you _don't_ call `sync` in between `begin` and `end`? Do you get terminated then? If not, it seems to me that that proves that you are being terminated because of something you do in `sync`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep doing tests and experiments to fix this. I appreciate the help. I'll let you know when I fix this. Thanks,

Comment: Updated CocoaPods that seemed to fix the error for now. Something weird with AFNetworking/FMDB I think. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Great work. You might want to answer your own question. This could be useful to others!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question here. AFNetworking and FMDB happened to be out of date. Updating them through cocoa pods seems to have fixed the problem.

Comment: Had the same problem today. Crash when calling `endBackgroundTask:` in the background within a AFNetworking callback block. Fixed it by wrapping the call to `endBackgroundTask:` in a dispatch_after.